# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of "} when posting data using C#

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone, multipart, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to multipart a rest web service using C# from my Windows Phone.

For this I am using the httpClient.

Even if the string I am sending is this:

```
{"AuthenticationRequest":{"company":"3000","identificationCode":"111", "username":"jack","password":"paz"}}
```

I am receiving this message description in my response body:

**A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of "}**

Here is my code:

```
public async Task postHttpClient(string serviceUrl, string requestObj)
        {
            try
            {

                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

               MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                Debug.WriteLine("requestObject: " + requestObject);
                content.Add(new StringContent(requestObj, Encoding.UTF8), "AuthenticationRequest");

                var responseVar = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, content);
                responseVar.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                Debug.WriteLine("responseVar: " + responseVar.ToString());

                var body = await responseVar.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("body: " + body);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("e: " + e.ToString());
            }
}
```

- Please what am I doing wrong?

Note: the first letter of my variable is { as obtained by

```
Debug.WriteLine("first letter: " + requestObj[0]);
```

I also trimmed that variable with no changes.

Comment: If you check the request contents' bytes, does it start with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) or is the first character '{'?

Comment: @GrawCube, how should I check it?

Comment: use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myStringVariable)` to get the bytes and whatever is your preferred debugging method to view them. Anything that shows the bytes as hexadecimal - I think Visual Studio can change the view of the local/watched variables if you right click on them.

Comment: @GrawCube, in the debug view the first chars are still {\"

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with your service expecting application/json content and you are sending multipart/form-data.

Try this:

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(serviceUrl));
message.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var result = await client.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: why did you state that?